# How to take two digit from string in java?

Tags: java, string, security

If user insert string that have ascii code numbers such as

```
S="7289"
```

I want to take two digit 72 and make computations on it then and 89 and apply operations on it , how i can do it 
.. and i want after these operations convert to their ascii code ? such as 72=H 
This is my code (part of the code) !

```
System.out.println("Enter CipherText : ");
String CipherText =scanner.next();
System.out.println("Using Private Key :(d,n) ("+d+","+n+")");
String ss="";
for(int i=0;i<CipherText.length();i++){
      /*String sub =CipherText.substring(i, i++);*/
      BigInteger bigIntValue1 = new BigInteger(CipherText);
      String D= bigIntValue1.modPow(d,n).toString();
      /*char ch1 = CipherText.charAt(i);
      String strAscii = String.valueOf(ch1);*/
      ss+=CipherText+" ";
}
System.out.println("Plain Text is :"+ss);
```

Comment: Does the initial string has 4 symbols in it or it can be dynamic (longer or shorter)? Cause then the splitting should be done in a loop

Comment: yes it is a dynamic .. the user insert the digits as string ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also give you the char 72=H or H.

```
public class PrintASCIIChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "7289";
       String c = Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 2)));

       System.out.println("Printing: " + c);
    }

}
```

Comment: i write your code but it print nothing :/  <pre> BigInteger bigIntValue1 = new BigInteger(CipherText);
           String D= bigIntValue1.modPow(d,n).toString();
           String dd= Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(D.substring(0,1))); <code>

Comment: shouldn't substring be (0,2)?

Comment: NO ,still not work :/ i think there is an error in BigInteger that give an number that didn't from ascii code !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substring` method.

```
String str1 = str.substring(0, 2);
```

First parameter is the initial index of the string, second parameter the last index of the characters you want to take.

Comment: the second parameter is the ending index, exclusive

Comment: but i want to take 2 by 2 :/ , should i have 2 for loop ?!

Comment: it's one: `substring(i*2,(i*2)+2);`

Comment: it still not work , give me error :- String index out of range

Comment: you should cycle from `i=0` to `i=n-2` in your `for` loop (with `n` the size of the string)

Answer (score 0):

Use the method string.split in its 2 overloaded versions
`public String substring(int beginIndex)` and `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

their respective docs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String S = "7289";
    String highPart = S.substring(0, 2);
    String lowPart = S.substring(2);
    System.out.println(highPart + lowPart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findMaxNumber(String str) {
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

        String ss = str.substring(i, i + 2);

        list.add(Integer.valueOf(ss));
        
        Collections.sort(list);

    }
    int xx = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    return xx;

}

System.out.println(TwoDigitFragmentNumber.findMaxNumber("50525"));
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.